# Relations not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

This will be fairly quick and easy for most of you...I have a table called `types`, and another called `projects`. A project can only have one type, but a type can have many projects. For instance a community garden project and a playground project can both have the type of 'greenspace'. So I have set up a `has_many` association. In my types model I have this:

```
has_many :projects
```

and in my projects model I don't have anything (I previously had `has_one` in it but upon looking at the docs it seemed incorrect). In the projects#show view I would like the name of the type to display. The parks project's view should say 'greenspace'. but I am getting the error

```
undefined method `type' for #<Project:0x007ffdd14fcde8>
```

I am trying to access that name using:

```
<h3>Type: <%= @project.type.project_type %> </h3>
```

i have also tried:

```
<h3>Type: <%= @project.type_id.project_type %> </h3>
```

but of course `type_id` gives a number, and there is no `project_type` for a number. `project_type` being the name of the column which holds the string data 'greenspace'. Am I accessing it wrong? Or have I set it up incorrectly?

Also in my schema, projects looks like this:

```
create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "type_id"
  t.text     "description"
  t.integer  "money_needed"
  t.integer  "money_raised"
  t.float    "interest_offered"
  t.datetime "end_date"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "url"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Project model you should state:

```
belongs_to => :type
```

In general, for most associations there is going to be an inverse. Not always, as you might have multiple associations in Type for Project. For example as well as your current has_many :projects, you might have others to return only projects that are unfinished, and such an association would not need an inverse.

Bear in mind that when you state: @project.type Rails is going to look for a method on @project. The association is what provides this method, and effectively the result is then the Type object that is referenced by the Project. It's important to realise that @project.type only returns a Type because the association tells it to -- the magic does not extent to just inferring that that is what is wanted.

Comment: Well I didn't post the entire project model. A project should belong to a user, and have a type. Does that change anything? Or can it belong to more than one table without being polymorphic, since in my understanding of polymorphism, the project would be able to belong to an instance of either table, but not both at the same time which it would need to

Comment: I've got myself in quite a tangle with six tables that all need to have multiple associations :/

Comment: thank you, it worked! I am off to do some more googling now lol :)

Answer (score 1):

Project can belong_to both. Like this

```
#app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type
  belongs_to :user
  #...
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  #...
end

#app/models/type.rb
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  #...
end
```

Comment: yes, after some googling around i set it up like that except added a foreign key to both, so it looks like ` belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'user_id'` - thank you for jumping in to help clarify it further. IDK what I would do without you folks on SO.  I found the answer to that part of my question already,  but maybe someone else will find this useful as well :)